# Windows Service don't runs properly c#

Tags: c#, windows-services

My windows service runs properly if I debug or run as console application, but if I install, it shows in services but doesn't runs at all. Please Help

This is main function

```
static void main(){

if (Environment.UserInteractive)
            {

                string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Service1";
                // Determine whether the directory exists.
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    //di.Delete(); 
                }




                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Service1\\program.txt", true);
                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : Here if\n");
                //     sw.WriteLine("userprofile " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + " : ");
                //    sw.WriteLine("application data " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + " : ");
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();

                Console.WriteLine("here1");
                Service1 service1 = new Service1();
                string[] args = { "Kun", "Singh" };
                service1.TestStartupAndStop(args);
            }
            else
            {
                string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Service1";
                // Determine whether the directory exists.
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    //di.Delete(); 
                }




                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\Service1\\program.txt", true);
                sw.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + " : Here else\n");
           //     sw.WriteLine("userprofile " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) + " : ");
            //    sw.WriteLine("application data " + Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + " : ");
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();





                Console.WriteLine("here2");
                // Put the body of your old Main method here.
                ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]
                {
                new Service1()
                };
                ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);


                // RunAsync().Wait();
                Service1 myServ = new Service1();
                myServ.write("hello bb");
                Console.Read();
            }
```

Comment: Did you make sure that the service is running? Go to run and type in Services.msc hit enter to see all running services.

Comment: its running only I even tried to restart....       Code is fine mostly as in debug mode all files are written and also DB works...  but if use installutil.exe it installs but nothing happens....   I don't whats the problem earlier it ran in sample program ....  Is there any way debug seeply

Comment: I even tried  
        [Conditional("DEBUG_SERVICE")]
        private static void DebugMode()
        {
            Debugger.Break();
        }   its working in debug mode

Answer (score 1):

Might because of Environment.UserInteractive is returning false. You are running a service which means there is no user interface. See [Environment.UserInteractive Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.userinteractive(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The UserInteractive property reports false for a Windows process or a
>   service like IIS that runs without a user interface. If this property
>   is false, do not display modal dialogs or message boxes because there
>   is no graphical user interface for the user to interact with.

I suggest try changing the condition to if (!Environment.UserInteractive)

Comment: I don't know but I added new wix setup in same solution and now everything works, perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I just made a new setup WIX and now its working, though there is second problem...  I have some references in my windows service project, How can I include them in setup as I when install and run, i have log file which says xxx.dll is missing

I have following references -> jose-jwt.dll , entity framework..

So how do I setup along with reference files